# Manifest Merger failed with multiple errors

Tags: android, android-studio

Buena tarde!! Estoy recibiendo este error y no se por que es, espero me puedan ayudar.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
```

> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

#### AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.udiaz.chat">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        
    <activity android:name="co.chatsdk.ui.login.LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data android:name="firebase_url" android:value="@string/firebase_url" />
    <meta-data android:name="firebase_root_path" android:value="@string/firebase_root_path" />
    <meta-data android:name="firebase_storage_url" android:value="@string/firebase_storage_url" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Este es mi build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.udiaz.chatprueba"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(path: ':chat_sdk_ui')
    compile project(path: ':chat_sdk_firebase_push')
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Este es el log.

> 11-13 14:05:19.892 1147-1517/? E/Drm: Failed to find drm plugin 11-13
> 14:05:23.041 1722-1722/com.google.android.gms.persistent
> E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null

Comment: el error dice que debes buscar el log, si no lo entiendes colocalo en tu pregunta para poderte ayudar

Comment: coloca el log que te da Android Studio

Comment: Como comenta Bourne revisa el Log , Que valores se tienen definidos en tu Strings.xml?

Comment: Me parece que tu problema está en el `gradle`, no en el `Manifest`. A no ser que una de esas Activity no existan en el proyecto. Es muy probable que tengas dos librerías con versiones incomptabiles. Si [editas tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/117076/edit) poniendo tu archivo gradle de app podríamos revisar.

Comment: El logCat es la clave Jaja

Comment: Buena tarde!! agregue mi gradle y el log que me salio!!, anteriormente me salio que el emulador necesitaba una cuenta de gmail, se la añadi y ahora me salió lo de Bluetooth. muchas gracias

Comment: Si estas intentando usar BLUETOOTH con el emulador , no podras realizarlo , para probar te recomiendo utilizar un telefono fisico ,!

Comment: eso es lo extraño que no quiero utilizar bluetooth, solo que sea por parte de las librerias que uso pero no es asi!! Esta es la que estoy intentando implementar https://github.com/chat-sdk/chat-sdk-android

Comment: No es solamente bluetooth, tampoco DRM es soportado en emuladores. Debes probar la app conectada por cable USB a un teléfono.

Comment: @UlisesDíaz te recomiendo que uses un Smartphone, no la maquina virtual (emulador)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Que tal les informo que mi problema estaba en el gradle

```
Merging Errors: Error: uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library /Users/omnius/Desktop/Chatprueba/chat_sdk_firebase_adapter/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="co.chatsdk.firebase" to force usage
```

tenia minSdkVersion distintas. disculpen las molestias pero soy nuevo con Android Studio.
Gracias!!

Comment: Por eso es importante revisar el Log, en ocasiones puede ser la diferencia de estar un par de minutos solucionando algo en lugar de todo un día...

Comment: Te lo dije en el cuarto comentario de la pregunta. ¿Al parecer no lo revisaste en ese momento? Te habrías ahorrado 4 horas de depuración.

Comment: si!! muchas gracias a Todos!

Comment: @UlisesDíaz recuerda marcar tu respuesta como correcta para dar por cerrada la pregunta, lo puedes haces despues de dos dias, saludos